# How to pass user defined function inside TfidfVectorizer.fit_transform()

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, user-defined-functions, tfidfvectorizer, nlp

I have function for text preprocessing which is simply removing stopwords as:

```
def text_preprocessing():
    df['text'] = df['text'].apply(word_tokenize)
    df['text']=df['text'].apply(lambda x: [item for item in x if item not in stopwords])
    new_array=[]
    for keywords in df['text']: #converts list of words into string
         P=" ".join(str(x) for x in keywords)
         new_array.append(P)
    df['text'] = new_array
    return df['text']
```

I want to pass `text_preprocessing()` into another function `tf_idf()` which gives feature matrix what I essentially did as:-

```
def tf_idf():
    tfidf = TfidfVectorizer()
    feature_array = tfidf.fit_transform(text_preprocessing)
    keywords_data=pd.DataFrame(feature_array.toarray(), columns=tfidf.get_feature_names())
    return keywords_data
```

I got an error as `TypeError: 'function' object is not iterable`

Comment: [documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer.html#sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer.fit_transform)  - fit_transform expects an iterable which yields either str, unicode or file objects, not a function

Comment: your `text_preprocessing` function returns an iterable, so you simply need to just call it i.e. `feature_array = tfidf.fit_transform(text_preprocessing())`.

Comment: inside function td_idf() I need to use reset_index for dataframe df. I have done df=df.reset_index(drop=True). but got an error as "df is not defined"?

Comment: please modify your post, you are adding more details than provided, and that is on you to show. further you have a lot of global variables in your code. this error would most likely happen because of that

Comment: my function got worked properly  but cant able to reset_index for df in function tf_idf().

Comment: If you clear your workspace and follow Asish M's second comment your functions work. However, your text_preprocessing function does unnecessary things - tokenization, stop-word removal, then reconstructing the strings in the 'text' column. This can all be done by TfidfVectorizer itself. Please consider the answer below as an alternative approach.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than building additional functions for stop-word removal you can simply pass a custom list of stop-words to TfidfVectorizer. As you can see in the example below "test" is successfully excluded from the Tfidf vocabulary.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer

# Setting up
numbers = np.random.randint(1, 5, 3)
text = ['This is a test.', 'Is this working?', "Let's see."]
df = pd.DataFrame({'text': text, 'numbers': numbers})

# Define custom stop words and instantiate TfidfVectorizer with them
my_stopwords = ['test'] # the list can be longer
tfidf = TfidfVectorizer(stop_words=my_stopwords)
text_tfidf = tfidf.fit_transform(df['text'])

# Optional - concatenating tfidf with df
df_tfidf = pd.DataFrame(text_tfidf.toarray(), columns=tfidf.get_feature_names())
df = pd.concat([df, df_tfidf], axis=1)

# Initial df
df
Out[133]: 
   numbers              text
0        2   This is a test.
1        4  Is this working?
2        3        Let's see.

tfidf.vocabulary_
Out[134]: {'this': 3, 'is': 0, 'working': 4, 'let': 1, 'see': 2}

# Final df
df
Out[136]: 
   numbers              text        is       let       see      this   working
0        2   This is a test.  0.707107  0.000000  0.000000  0.707107  0.000000
1        4  Is this working?  0.517856  0.000000  0.000000  0.517856  0.680919
2        3        Let's see.  0.000000  0.707107  0.707107  0.000000  0.000000
```